# Safely store database password when working locally

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, passwords, local

I wanted to make an app(web app) locally(which is my notebook).
Just for my own use, that is I why want 
to do it locally(I am not sure if that is called a web app, hence the bracket).

I know this is a very rare case, but if for some reason my
notebook got stolen, and they can access my database in there
because the password to login to my database is stored in a file locally too.

How do I safely store my database password?
Should I use cloud(Google drive?)?
Is this even possible? Or I just have to face it?

More information:

1) My database is stored locally too. I am using MAMP on a Mac

2) I access it by opening a file that contains the database password in my notebook, and then take that password to use it to open the database.

3) I'm using PHP, using PDO object to access my Mysql

Comment: Is your database local to the notebook, or is it a remote database, such as a web server? If indeed it is a remote database, what method are you logging into it? There is a lot of information still needed to find a solution to your problem, and I'm sure many of us would be willing to help.

Comment: I added this in 'More information' section. And to answer, yes database is locally to my notebook :)